# How to collect all xml elements in a list?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson-dataformat-xml

I am using `jackson-dataformat-xml`.

I have the following classes:

```
public class CTHotel {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "basic-info")
    private HotelBaseInfo hotelBaseInfo;

    //other properties and getters and setters
}

public class HotelBaseInfo {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "hotel-name")
    private String hotelName;

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "hotel-amenities")
    private List<HotelAmenity> hotelAmenities;

    //other properties and getters/setters
}

public class HotelAmenity {
    private String category;
    private String description;

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "amenities")
    private List<String> amenities;

    //other properties and getters/setters
}
```

My XML is this:

```
<hotels>
    <hotel>
        <basic-info>
            <hotel-name>Hotel XYZ</hotel-name>
            <hotel-amenities>
                <hotel-amenity>
                    <category>F&B</category>
                    <description>Random Text</description>
                    <amenities>
                        <amenity>Cafe</amenity>
                        <amenity>Bar</amenity>
                        <amenity>Rastaurant</amenity>
                    </amenities>
                </hotel-amenity>
                <hotel-amenity>
                ...
                </hotel-amenity>   
            </hotel-amenities>
        </basic-info>
    </hotel>
    <hotel>
    ...
    </hotel>
</hotels>
```

My question is, how can I map `amenities` as list of strings in my `HotelAmenity` class as mentioned above ? What annotation should I use on `amenities` field ?

`@JacksonXmlElementWrapper` annotation on `hotelAmenities` field of `Hotel` class is working just fine.

I get the below error while mapping :

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@507bcc81; line: 3, column: 1039] (through reference chain: com.example.response.HotelSearchResponse["hotels"]->java.util.ArrayList[2]->com.example.response.CTHotel["basic-info"]->com.example.response.HotelBaseInfo["hotel-amenities"]->java.util.ArrayList[1]->com.example.response.HotelAmenity["amenities"]->java.util.ArrayList[9])
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:148) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.mappingException(DeserializationContext.java:857) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code, that I hope would answer your question:

```
/**Class Hotels*/
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "hotels")
public class Hotels {

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private List<Hotel> hotel;

    //Other getters and setters
}

/**Class Hotel*/
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "hotel")
public class Hotel {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "basic-info")
    private HotelBaseInfo hotelBaseInfo;

    //Other getters and setters
}

/**Class HotelBaseInfo*/
public class HotelBaseInfo {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "hotel-name")
    private String hotelName;

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "hotel-amenities")
    private List<HotelAmenity> hotelAmenities;

    //Other getters and setters

}

/**Class HotelAmenity*/
public class HotelAmenity {
    private String category;
    private String description;

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "amenities")
    private List<Amenities> amenity;

    static class Amenities {
        @JacksonXmlText
        private String value;
    }

    //Other getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:

```
public class JacksonXmlParsing {

@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "hotels")
static class HotelSearchResponse {

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "hotel")
    private List<CTHotel> hotels;

    //other properties and getters and setters
}

static class CTHotel {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "hotel-name")
    private String hotelName;

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "hotel-amenities")
    private List<HotelAmenity> hotelAmenities;

    //other properties and getters and setters
}

static class HotelAmenity {
    private String category;
    private String description;

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper
    private List<String> amenities;

    //other properties and getters/setters
}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();

        File file = new File("./src/main/resources/file.xml");
        HotelSearchResponse response = xmlMapper.readValue(file, HotelSearchResponse.class);
        System.out.println(response);
    }

}
```

Output:
`HotelSearchResponse(hotels=[CTHotel(hotelName=Hotel XYZ, hotelAmenities=[HotelAmenity(category=F&B, description=Random Text, amenities=[Cafe, Bar, Rastaurant])])])`

But `basic-info` tag is missed, I could find out why.

Comment: I have edited my question. Turns out that my minimized question didn't get me the answer I wanted. Please have a look now. I have also mentioned the error that I am getting.

Comment: @mantri are those three classes you only have? And can you please provide the code you're using for parsing given xml?

Comment: The list of hotels is again wrapped in a `HotelSearchResponse` class.
This is how I am mapping the xml: 
`XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();`
`HotelSearchResponse hotelSearchResponse = mapper.readValue(xmlStr, HotelSearchResponse.class);`

Comment: For the `@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "hotel")` you used the name of child tag as `localName` but for `@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "hotel-amenities")` you used the name of wrapper tag as `localName`. Why so ?